# Wire a 5 wire down draft remote motor / can this be done?

Tags: electrical

I currently have a Thermador downdraft range w/ remote blower on the roof.  The  range has failed.  This blower unit was very expensive and I hate to chuck it.   Am wondering if it can be used elsewhere.  What I would like is to wire it to a 3 speed wall switch.  Can this be done.  I would hire it out but don't want to waste the cost of an electrician if it is not do-able or safe.  The blower has 5 wires. (white-red-blue-black-green)

Comment: Should be doable...

Comment: Thanks so much.  I have all installation info and diagrams.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should work. I found this wiring diagram below on Thermador's website. It's for a 4 speed blower, but it's basically the same concept for the electrician except one less wire. Black, red, and blue are the three speeds. White is the neutral. Green is the ground. This diagram might not be relevant to your model or installation and so any information that you still have on the blower would help out the electrician I'm sure. However, it should be as simply as just connecting power to the switch and then have it branch off and wire nutted together with the blower.

[image: Wiring diagram]